# handle null recursively in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I want to execute eval on a string "bean.data.id", but "bean.data" is null. is there any way to make this expression do not throw exception? or what is the right way to handle this? Thanks a lot!

```
${name?eval}

name = 'bean.data.id'
bean = {"data": null}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this (assuming printing nothing on `null` is fine):

```
${'(${name})!'?eval}
```